# Creating NSArray of objects from a Text File

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create an NSArray of Strings from a text file.

Here's the code i've been using:

```
NSString *title = @"facts";
    NSString *type = @"txt";
    NSString *seperation = @"/n";
    NSMutableArray *factArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                            pathForResource:title ofType:type] 
                                                                    encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:NULL] 
                                                         componentsSeparatedByString:seperation]];
```

But it seems to give some extra objects with no text in, i need to fix this.
Just if it helps this the text file I've been using it with:

> /nFeet sizes in England are measured
>   in Barleycorns. /n
>
> Elephants laugh and cry. /n
>
> Trousers kill 12 people a year. /n
>
> The lion that roars in the MGM logo is
>   called Volney. /n
>
> The wife of a Sultan is called a
>   Sultana. /n
>
> Brad Pitt's real name is William. /n
>
> There are more than 5000 ladybird
>   species. /n
>
> US lavatories are 100 times more
>   dangerous than British ones. In 1996,
>   43,687 Americans were hospitalized
>   after toilet disasters. /n
>
> The statue of liberty is made of
>   bronze and was given to the Americans
>   by the French. /n
>
> The Irish gave bagpipes to the Scots
>   as a joke. It back fired! /n
>
> Your foot is the same length as the
>   distance between your wrist and elbow.
>   /n
>
> A rat can swim non-stop for 72 hours.
>   /n
>
> The odds of being killed in a car
>   crash in Britain are the same as being
>   killed in an accident inside your own
>   home: 1 in 10,000. /n
>
> In 1996, 12 people in Britain were
>   rushed to hospital after a paperclip
>   incident. /n

Comment: Just in case, line break is \n, not /n... But maybe you have written /n in your file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the text file:

> ```
> Feet sizes in England are measured in Barleycorns.
> Elephants laugh and cry. 
> Trousers kill 12 people a year. 
> The lion that roars in the MGM logo is called Volney. 
> The wife of a Sultan is called a Sultana. 
> Brad Pitt's real name is William. 
> There are more than 5000 ladybird species. 
> US lavatories are 100 times more dangerous than British ones. In 1996, 43,687 Americans were hospitalized after toilet disasters. 
> The statue of liberty is made of bronze and was given to the Americans by the French. 
> The Irish gave bagpipes to the Scots as a joke. It back fired! 
> Your foot is the same length as the distance between your wrist and elbow. 
> A rat can swim non-stop for 72 hours. 
> The odds of being killed in a car crash in Britain are the same as being killed in an accident inside your own home: 1 in 10,000. 
> In 1996, 12 people in Britain were rushed to hospital after a paperclip incident.
> ```

Here is the code:

```
NSString *title = @"facts";
NSString *type = @"txt";
NSString *separation = @"\n";
NSString *fileText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:title ofType:type] encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableArray *facts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[fileText componentsSeparatedByString:separation]];

NSLog(@"%@", [facts description]);
```

Here is the output array:

```
(
"Feet sizes in England are measured in Barleycorns. ",
"Elephants laugh and cry. ",
"Trousers kill 12 people a year. ",
"The lion that roars in the MGM logo is called Volney. ",
"The wife of a Sultan is called a Sultana. ",
"Brad Pitt's real name is William. ",
"There are more than 5000 ladybird species. ",
"US lavatories are 100 times more dangerous than British ones. In 1996, 43,687 Americans were hospitalized after toilet disasters. ",
"The statue of liberty is made of bronze and was given to the Americans by the French. ",
"The Irish gave bagpipes to the Scots as a joke. It back fired! ",
"Your foot is the same length as the distance between your wrist and elbow. ",
"A rat can swim non-stop for 72 hours. ",
"The odds of being killed in a car crash in Britain are the same as being killed in an accident inside your own home: 1 in 10,000. ",
"In 1996, 12 people in Britain were rushed to hospital after a paperclip incident. "
)
```

There were 14 lines of text in the input file you specified. There was one extra newline at the beginning of the file. This accounts for one of the extra count. I can only surmise that there was an extra new line somewhere in the actual file. Perhaps at the end?

There were a couple of things I did to make this work.
I changed `@"/n"` to `@"\n"` 
We pass `nil` to `error:` not `NULL`
And I logged the description of the NSMutableArray, which I chose to initialize in a second step for readability. 
I also got rid of the extra newline at the top of the file, and made sure there wasn't one at the end.

Answer (score 1):

How about logging the array to the console (or printing it using "po factArray")? The extra objects might be empty lines, maybe? If so, you can just remove all objects (strings) that isEqualToString:@"" ...

Comment: When I log the array using `for (NSString *text in self.facts)``{`` NSLog``(@"%@",`` text);`` }``it only shows 14 items when the count shows 16.

Comment: Post it. Append the output to your question so we can see what you see.